# Parsing json to c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#

Am getting this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
>   occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using trialss.Resources;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace trialss
{
public class Token
{
    public string Token_No { get; set; }
    public string Transaction_Date { get; set; }
    public string Transaction_Amount { get; set; }
    public string Purchased_Units { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Token> Token { get; set; }
    public int success { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void clikeed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("my link"));

    }
    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,         DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

        foreach (var book in rootObject.Token)
        {

        }

    }
} 
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: The following line always gets the exception                                              var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using [Windows.Data.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.aspx)? I use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) to download a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx). Then I parse it using some classes (depending on the requirements) that has the namespace mentioned above.